# Directing output from a command to input of a C file

Tags: c, unix, pipe

So I have a text file that I am using which contains multiple color codes. I want to use the grep command for regex and then pipe it to sort by their alpha value and output the result to a new file. But in the middle of it I want to use my custom C program that concatenates alpha values to codes that don't already have them  which I then want to sort. The commands and C program have been tested separately and work fine, my problem is piping the output of the grep into the input of my C file and then sort it and output it to a new file. I am doing all of this inside a makefile and it currently compiles but prints nothing to the new output file.

Command:

```
build-test: test.c
  gcc test.c -o test

run-test: build-test
  grep -iE '^#[a-f0-9]{6}([a-f0-9]{2})?$$' colours.txt | ./test | sort --stable -rk1.8 > rgba-colours.txt
```

C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    int lines = 1;
    char line[1000], alpha[] = "ff";

    extern FILE *stdin;

    stdin = fopen("colours.txt", "r");

    while (fgets(line, 1000, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        line[strlen(line) - 1] = 0;
        lines += 1;

        if (strlen(line) == 7)
        {
            strcat(line, alpha);
        }
    }

    fclose(stdin);
    return 0;
 }
```

Colours.txt

```
#b293a6
#a69d36a2
#067806
#7f0bf7ef
#f8b366
#042847421
#8946d7
#c927d4
#3e568bff
#3e1ce1
#11570a00
#e02a67
#afe6e
#1a283af
#44999e
#b07c2292
#0e6da9
#31511bxf
#25680a10
#866156
#dd85
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be a `Makefile`? If so it won't work at all because you have to use tabs. And `grep ...` command will never run.

Comment: That was just a simple mistake when making the question, I use tabs in the makefile

Comment: Can you also provide `colours.txt`?

Comment: Question has been updated with the text file

Comment: Your `test.c` prints nothing to the stdout. Add `puts(line);` after processing each line in `while` loop.

Comment: `stdin` is already open and it receives the output of `grep`. No need to open `stdin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Makefile` should look like this:

```
run-test: build-test
    grep -iE '^#[a-f0-9]{6}([a-f0-9]{2})?$$' colours.txt | ./test | sort --stable -rk1.8 > rgba-colours.txt

build-test: test.c
    gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic test.c -o test

clean:
    rm -f test rgba-colours.txt
```

I have also added a `clean` target that users might expect to be
present that will remove all output artifacts. `-f` is used so that
`rm`, and hence `make clean` itself will not fail if files are
missing.

Your `test.c` does not read `stdin` and prints nothing to the
stdout. Use `stdin` in `fgets`, add `puts(line);` after processing
each line in while loop, and use correct `main` prototype like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int lines = 1;
    char line[1000], alpha[] = "ff";

    while (fgets(line, 1000, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        line[strlen(line) - 1] = 0;
        lines += 1;

        if (strlen(line) == 7)
        {
            strcat(line, alpha);
        }

        puts(line);
    }

    fclose(stdin);
    return 0;
 }
```